# jdbcTemplate with c3p0 hangs

Tags: c3p0, jdbctemplate, apache-commons-dbcp

I have a very simple test that works with dbcp connection pool and forever hangs with c3p0 (0.9.2).

```
    private String query="select ROWID from SOMETABLE "  +
            " where  rownum <= 100 for update skip locked";
private String deleteQuery = "delete from SOMETABLE where ROWID = ?";

public void retrieve() throws Exception {
    while (retrieveChunk() > 0){
        //do nothing
    }
}

@Transactional
private int retrieveChunk(){

    final List<Object[]> delPar = new ArrayList<Object[]>(100);
    template.query(query, new RowCallbackHandler() {
        public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
            String rowid = rs.getString(1);
            delPar.add(new String[]{rowid});
        }
    });
    template.batchUpdate(deleteQuery, delPar);
    return delPar.size();
}
```

Spring context:

```
    <bean id="connPool" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="user" value="**"/>
    <property name="password" value="**"/>
    <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@****"/>
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="0"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="connPool"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

What is wrong with c3p0 configuration?

Update - log4j output:

```
12:17:18,449 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:435 - Executing SQL query [select ROWID from SOMETABLE  where  rownum <= 100 for update skip locked]
```

12:17:18,465 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:110 - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
12:17:18,809 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:327 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
12:17:18,809 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:881 - Executing SQL batch update [delete from SOMETABLE   where ROWID = ?]
12:17:18,824 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:570 - Executing prepared SQL statement [delete from SOMETABLE where ROWID = ?]
12:17:18,824 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:110 - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
12:17:18,887 DEBUG JdbcUtils:362 - JDBC driver supports batch updates
12:17:18,902 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:327 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
12:17:18,902  INFO PlainJdbcTableRetriever:36 - JdbcTemplateRetriever retrieve started
12:17:18,902 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:435 - Executing SQL query [select ROWID from SOMETABLE  where  rownum <= 100 for update skip locked]
12:17:18,902 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:110 - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
12:17:18,934 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:327 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
12:17:18,934 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:881 - Executing SQL batch update [delete from SOMETABLE where ROWID = ?]
12:17:18,934 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:570 - Executing prepared SQL statement [delete from SOMETABLE where ROWID = ?]
12:17:18,934 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:110 - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
12:17:18,934 DEBUG JdbcUtils:362 - JDBC driver supports batch updates
12:17:18,934 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:327 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
12:17:18,934 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:435 - Executing SQL query [select ROWID from SOMETABLE  where  rownum <= 100 for update skip locked]
12:17:18,934 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:110 - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
12:17:18,981 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:327 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
12:17:18,981 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:881 - Executing SQL batch update [delete from SOMETABLE where ROWID = ?]
12:17:18,981 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:570 - Executing prepared SQL statement [delete from SOMETABLE where ROWID = ?]
12:17:18,981 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:110 - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
12:17:18,981 DEBUG JdbcUtils:362 - JDBC driver supports batch updates
12:17:18,996 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:327 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
12:17:18,996 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:435 - Executing SQL query [select ROWID from SOMETABLE  where  rownum <= 100 for update skip locked]
12:17:18,996 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:110 - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
12:17:19,012 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:327 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
12:17:19,012 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:881 - Executing SQL batch update [delete from SOMETABLE where ROWID = ?]
12:17:19,012 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:570 - Executing prepared SQL statement [delete from SOMETABLE where ROWID = ?]
12:17:19,012 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:110 - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
12:17:19,012 DEBUG JdbcUtils:362 - JDBC driver supports batch updates

Comment: what's going on in your logs? when you say "hang" does your application just freeze entirely? have you provoked a Thread dump to see what's going on?

Comment: btw acquireIncrement=1 is a bad idea. but it's not likely to be the cause of your problem. also, initialPoolSize should be at least 1, since that's minPoolSize. but again, that's not the cause of your troubles.

Comment: Yes, my application just freezed.

Comment: we'll really need more info -- log messages and/or thread dumps -- to understand what might be happening.

Comment: How can I enable logging in c3p0?
As I can see I have to recompile c3p0.
Can you share debug enabled c3p0 binary file?

Comment: no, you don't have to recompile anything. regardless of c3p0 is compiled, it logs everything at or above INFO level. the distributed binary of c3p0 has DEBUG set to true -- it logs everything, if your logging library is permissive enough. you should already have c3p0 messages in your application logs. if you need more information, you'll need to reset the level of your log library for c3p0's loggers to DEBUG or FINE/FINER/FINEST (again, depending on your log library). But the first step is to find what is already being logged.

Comment: I've updated debug messages